# Who is the giant wolf Fenris?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In the film Thor Ragnarok, Fenris helps Hela take over Asgard and goes after Thor, Loki, Valkerie, and Bruce/the Hulk. In the original myths, Fenrir( as he was named), was Hela's brother. Is he also her brother, pet, or just an ally in the film?

Comment: are you sure she didn't call him Fenrir?

Comment: @KutuluMike It was Fenris, I paused for a moment there as well.  I figured it's a bit like how Hela is apparently based on [Hel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hel_(being)).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if Hela called him Fenris or Fenrir (I thought she said Fenrir, because I wasn't expecting it so it stood out), though both names refer to the same thing. (I believe "Fenris Wolf" is actually a mispronunciation/mistranslation of "Fenrir's Wolf")

In the movie, the wolf is Hela's "steed", similar to a war horse. He's more than a simple pet, and it's likely he has at least some degree of intelligence. Hela can be seen in the murals riding him to battle along wide Odin, for example.

In the comics material, [Fenris Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenris_Wolf_(Marvel_Comics)) is the son of Loki, a giant wolf-like creature from Asgard. He's more frequently associated with Loki's attempts to bring about Ragnarok, Hela did unchain him at least one for the same purpose. In the comics, she fails to bring about Ragnarok, but Loki later releases Fenris and a few other classic Thor enemies, who collectively manage to shatter Mjolnir and destroy Asgard. The movie seems to have taken many of these later Ragnarok story elements and put Hela into Loki's place, including transferring Fenris's allegiance to her.

Comment: not just the comics, norse mythology. The midgard serpent is also his child (not sure if that is the case in the comics). Saying that tho Hel is Loki child as well. Busy little scamp

Comment: @Naib So is Sleipnir, Odin's horse.

Comment: Yer. Norse mythology is funny. Like heimdel going around bedding old ladies

Comment: It's all a bit off from the mythology - Hel is associated with a canine, but its [Garmr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garmr), not Fenrir.  Fenrir is Hel's brother, but he ends up chained up the whole time.  Garmr is more or less the equivalent of Cerberus.

Answer (score 2):

Fenris is referred to similar to a pet (she refers to him as "my darling"), although she describes how she rode him in to war as illustrated in the Asgard paintings.  I believe she mentioned it as well, but I haven't seen the film enough to drop a quote for that last bit.

He is not her brother / Loki's child like in Norse mythology.